# Datetime - Find dates two days before variable date

Tags: python, datetime, flask, pythonanywhere

I have the following table.

I need to view all bookings two days before the booking_date.

```
class BookingInfo(Base):

__tablename__ = 'booking_info'

_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
booking_id = Column(Integer)
type_id = Column(Integer)
booking_date = Column(DATE)
```

I have tried the below.

```
new_booking_date = BookingInfo.booking_date.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
d1 = new_booking_date-timedelta(days=2)
```

but keep getting the error in PythonAnywhere 1292, "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1970-01-03 00:00:00'")
result = self._query(query)

I am sure this is down to the formatting but cannot quite determine how the code should be wrote.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `new_booking_date` seems to be a string? You can't subtract a timedelta from that, you'll need an instance of a datetime data type I'd say

Comment: Agreed with the above -- is there a particular reason why you're running it through `strftime` on the first line?

Comment: Thanks, When I originally tried it without the strftime thats when I got the Truncated error message. I was presuming the BookingInfo.booking_date field was including the time as well as the date.